# How can I make F9 key to compile (in C++) in VIM?

Tags: vim

I tried  `imap < F9 > :!g++ %` - (without spaces), but it doesn't work.

EDITED: So stupid, I wanted to say `map < F9 > :!g++ %` - without spaces...
But I figured out that the spaces are the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
:map <F9> :!g++ %
```

`imap` is for ignoring the mapping.

Next time you ask a question please provide more details on how exactly it did not work (what output did it have when you pressed F9? did nothing happen?).